# Magento2: Issue with salable quantity

Tags: magento2, salable

We have imported products to our website. For most of products salable quantity shows 0.

https://prnt.sc/tosm8b

We try run reindex but still salable quantity shows 0.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first take backup of your Database. After try this query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS
select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
`product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product`
on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`))) ;
```

After exceution of query just reindex and flush chahe

Comment: I had this table already created earlier and for half products salable quanity shows correct number. But for some products  still shown 0 and for many products it shows a negative quantity

Comment: Run this query: Take backup of inventory_source_item  table.

INSERT IGNORE INTO `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))